# install Beautiful soup at the remote server machine under Debian Linux

Tags: python, linux, installation, beautifulsoup

i need to install Beautiful soup at the remote server machine under Debian Linux (Python is there already). But i'am at home with Win 7 on my desktop. Would you guideline the installation process to me. All i have is the beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz file.

Comment: tried apt-get or pip? do you have physical access to server? if not, what protocol do you use?

Comment: Use ssh and then just install like you would otherwise? You don't give any real context here...

Comment: i use SSH protocol thru XShell4; i'm able to run Python's scripts there. Tryed `>>> easy_install python-beautifulsoup4 ` but helpless, didn't try `apt-get` or `pip`, but how to move the zipped package there, thru FTP?

Comment: use scp beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz username@servername:~/ to upload it to your home dir.

Comment: Should i type it in linux prompt or at Win command prompt?

Comment: tried it in XShell4 : `Xshell:\> scp beautifulsoup4-4.1.tar.gz root@servername:~/` - no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not download the file in server through Command line and do the usual installation

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/B/BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz#md5=44656527ef3ac9874ac4d1c9f35f70ee 
tar xvf BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
python setup.py install
```

Comment: The result is poor: wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/B/Beautiful
Soup-3.2.1.tar.gz#md5=44656527ef3ac9874ac4d1c9f35f70ee
--2012-09-12 17:24:53--  http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/B/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
Resolving pypi.python.org... 140.211.10.73
Connecting to pypi.python.org|140.211.10.73|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-09-12 17:24:53 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: thank you, now i succeded. I installed BeautifulSoup4-4.1.3, should i import as bs4?